# How to return most recend id based on user name and date - SQL

Tags: sql, google-cloud-sql

I have the current sql table bellow:

```
id user    date
1  john 2021-08-20
3  john 2021-08-24
5  john 2021-08-25
8  will 2021-08-25
9  will 2021-08-20
6  will 2021-08-18
```

I need to return the id's who have the most recent date, and with that, return a count of how many times the user appeared. And the id isn't always numered in crescent order by date, as the example bellow.

```
id user count
5  john   3
8  will   3
```

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Asked and answered [many times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+sql)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `qualify` to get the most recent row:

```
select t.*
from t
where 1=1
qualify row_number() over (partition by name order by date desc) = 1;
```

You can add a window function for the count:

```
select t.*,
       count(*) over (partition by name) as cnt
from t
where 1=1
qualify row_number() over (partition by name order by date desc) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT id, user, count(user) AS count
FROM table_name
Group by user
having date = max(date);
```